# Updating radio button selection in Shiny R

Tags: r, shiny

I am new to shiny and need to filter the selection for a radio button based on the selection from the previous radio button. Ultimately the selection from the second radio button will be used to generate an interactive plot….but I am not sure how to format the “updateRadioButtons” function.

Let me explain the desired result. In the example below, the “site” radio button will have “a” and “b” to select. If “site a” is selected, then I would like the options under the “sample” radio button to show selections for samples “1, 2, 3” and if “site b” is selected I would like the options under the “sample” radio button to show selections for samples “4, 5, 6”.

My actual data set will include 20 sites with 1000 unique samples and each site will have a different number of samples. Furthermore, new sites and samples will be added to this data set in the future.

Thanks in advance for any help. Take care.

```
site <- c('a','a','a','b','b','b')

sample <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

data1 <- data.frame(site, sample)

library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  sidebarPanel(
    radioButtons("site", "What site I want",
                 choices = unique(data1$site)),

    radioButtons("sample", "Samples at site",
                unique(data1$sample))),

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$site,{
    updateRadioButtons(session, "sample",
                       choices = input$sample)})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this worked on my system. Your code uses the current selection of `input$sample` which is only one value. Use this value, instead, to select the correct vector of choices.

```
observeEvent(input$site, {
    Choices <- data1$sample[data1$site == input$site]
    updateRadioButtons(session, "sample", choices = Choices)
  })
```

A further observation: You initialize the second radio button with all values `1:6` because that is what `unique(data1$sample)` will return. That will instantly be overwritten when `observeEvent(input$site ...` is called. For a brief instant, however, users should see `1:6`. You can improve by initializsing the choices `data1$sample[data1$site == "a"]`and setting the argument `ignoreInit` of `observeEvent` to `TRUE`. That'll set the correct value and will reduce any flickering on startup.
(edited)